# UITableViewRowAction handle click

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, xamarin, ios8

I am using the [UITableViewRowAction](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewRowAction_class/index.html) method in iOS 8 Beta 2+ to add custom buttons when swiping on a row in my table. I can't work out how to handle the click event though, it currently just crashed my app. I have tried the following:

```
public override UITableViewRowAction[] EditActionsForRow (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        List<UITableViewRowAction> items = new List<UITableViewRowAction>();

        UITableViewRowAction button = new UITableViewRowAction ();
        button.Title="Test";
        button.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray;
        button += delegate {   
            Console.WriteLine ("Hello World!");
        }; 

        items.Add(Button);

        return items.ToArray();
    }
```

However it would compile as I get the following:

```
Operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'MonoTouch.UIKit.UITableViewRowAction' and 'anonymous method'.
```

How do I assign a handler to click on the UITableViewRowAction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Monotouch**

```
public override UITableViewRowAction[] EditActionsForRow (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    UITableViewRowAction moreButton = UITableViewRowAction.Create (
        UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, 
        "More",
        delegate {
            Console.WriteLine ("Hello World!");
        });
    return new UITableViewRowAction[] { moreButton };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The success code looks like this:

**Swift**

```
var button = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Test", handler:{ action, indexpath in println("Hello World!"); });
```

**Objective-c**

```
UITableViewRowAction *button = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"Test" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
{
    NSLog("Hello World!");
}];
```